# Issues lining up multiple columns in beamer

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am working on a slide to use for a presentation. Right now the bottom left table does not line up with the bottom right table. I would like for the first row of each table to line up as the first row of each of the tables above line up. Is there any way to do this?

[image: Presentation]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
% Set theme to UNA2
\usetheme{UNA2}

\newcommand{\divides}{\bigm|}
\newcommand{\ndivides}{%
  \mathrel{\mkern.5mu % small adjustment
    % superimpose \nmid to \big|
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$\big|$\hidewidth\cr$\nmid$\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Quasigroups and the Sudoku Property}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|} 
\hline
1 & 3 & 2 & 4\\
\hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 1\\
\hline\hline
3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{1 mm}
\\ A $4\times4$ table with
\\ $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}           
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
\hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{1 mm}
\\ A Cayley Table representing
\\ a Quasigroup
\end{table}
\columnbreak
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c||c|c||c|c|}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline\hline
1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1\\
\hline\hline
3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{1 mm}
\\A labeled $4\times4$ table
\\ with $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c||c|c||c|c|}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline\hline
1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3\\
\hline\hline
3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{1 mm}
\\ The same Quasigroup with the
\\ Sudoku property
\end{table}
\end{multicols}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider just a suggestion in terms of displaying the information. You seem to be using row/column indices, which I've set using `\small`.

I've used [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) to highlight the blocks (requires a `fragile` frame):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,hhline}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small #1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Quasigroups and the Sudoku Property}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CC}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|}
    \mc{\phantom{1}} \\% Empty line
    \hline
    1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
    \hline
    2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
    \hhline{|=|=#=|=|}
    3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
    \hline
    4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
    \mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 2 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
    \hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
    \small 3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 4 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    \cline{2-5}
  \end{tabular} \\
  \begin{tabular}{c} A $4\times4$ table with \\ $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{c} A labeled $4\times4$ table \\ with $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks \end{tabular} \\[2\normalbaselineskip]
  %
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
    \mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-5}
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
    \mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
    \hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
    \small 3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \small 4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-5}
  \end{tabular} \\
  \begin{tabular}{c} A Cayley Table representing \\ a Quasigroup \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{c} The same Quasigroup with the \\ Sudoku property \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If this suggestion doesn't meet your needs, let me know...

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm still working through everything to get a grasp on all the commands you used, but everything looks perfect.